# How to prove $ y_1, \dots , y_n$ generate module M？

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over PID $R$, and $M$ is generated by $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$. Let $y_1=a_1\cdot x_1+\dots +a_n\cdot x_n$, and $\gcd(a_1, \dots , a_n)=1.$ Prove that there exist $y_2, \dots, y_n$ such that $y_1, \dots, y_n$ generate $M$.

Since $R$ is PID, there exist $u_1, \dots , u_n \in R$ such that $u_1a_1+ \dots +u_na_n=1$. I want to use this equation to prove it, but I have trouble constructing $y_2, \dots, y_n$. Any hint would be helpful！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, I'll reword the problem as follows . . .

Let $M$ be an $R$-module where $R$ is a PID, let $x_1,...,x_n\in M$ with $n\ge 2$, and let $y_1=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$ where $a_1,...,a_n\in R$ are such that $\text{gcd}(a_1,...,a_n)=1$.

**Claim:**$\;$There exist $y_2,...,y_n\in \langle{x_1,...,x_n}\rangle$ such that $\langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle=\langle{x_1,...,x_n}\rangle$.

**Proof:**

First suppose $n = 2$.

Let $a_1,a_2\in R$ be such that $\text{gcd}(a_1,a_2)=1$, and let $y_1=a_1x_1+a_2x_2$.

Since $\text{gcd}(a_1,a_2)=1$,  there exist  $u_1,u_2\in R$ such that $u_1a_1+u_2a_2=1$.

Let $y_2=-u_2x_1+u_1x_2$.

It's clear that $y_1,y_2\in \langle{x_1,x_2}\rangle$.

But identically we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
u_1y_1-a_2y_2
&=
u_1(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)-a_2(-u_2x_1+u_1x_2)
\\[4pt]
&=
(u_1a_1+u_2a_2)x_1+(u_1a_2-u_1a_2)x_2
\\[4pt]
&=
(1)(x_1)+(0)(x_2)
\\[4pt]
&=
x_1
\\[10pt]
u_2y_1+a_1y_2
&=
u_2(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)+a_1(-u_2x_1+u_1x_2)
\\[4pt]
&=
(u_2a_1-u_2a_1)x_1+(u_1a_1+u_2a_2)x_2
\\[4pt]
&=
(0)(x_1)+(1)(x_2)
\\[4pt]
&=
x_2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence $x_1,x_2\in \langle{y_1,y_2}\rangle$.

Thus $\langle{y_1,y_2}\rangle=\langle{x_1,x_2}\rangle$, so the claim holds for $n=2$.

Before continuing, we prove a simple lemma . . .

**Lemma:**

If $R$ is a UFD and $r_1,r_2\in R$, there exist $s_1,s_2\in R$ with $\text{gcd}(s_1,s_2)=1$ such that $r_1s_1+r_2s_2=0$.

**Proof of the lemma:**

If $r_1=0$ then letting $s_1=1$ and $s_2=0$ we have $\text{gcd}(s_1,s_2)=1$ and
$$
r_1s_1+r_2s_2
=
(0)(1)+(r_2)(0)
=
0+0
=
0
$$
Next suppose $r_1\ne 0$ and let 
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
s_1&=\frac{r_2}{d}\\[4pt]
s_2&=-\frac{r_1}{d}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
where $d=\text{gcd}(r_1,r_2)$.

Then we have $\text{gcd}(s_1,s_2)=1$ and
$$
r_1s_1+r_2s_2
=
(r_1)\left(\frac{r_2}{d}\right)+(r_2)\left(-\frac{r_1}{d}\right)
=
\frac{r_1r_2-r_1r_2}{d}
=
\frac{0}{d}
=
0
$$
which completes the proof of the lemma.

**Returning to the proof of the main claim . . .**

Proceeding by induction on $n$, let $n\ge 3$ and assume the claim holds for the case $n-1$.

Let $a_1,...,a_n\in R$ be such that $\text{gcd}(a_1,...,a_n)=1$, and let $y_1=\sum_{k=1}^na_kx_k$.

Since $\text{gcd}(a_1,...,a_n)=1$, at least one of $a_1,...,a_n$ must be nonzero.

Relabeling if necessary, assume $a_1\ne 0$.

Let $g=\text{gcd}(a_1,...,a_{n-1})$.

Let $r_1,...,r_{n-1}\in R$ be such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_ka_k=g$ and  $\text{gcd}(r_1,...,r_{n-1})=1$.

Applying the lemma, let $s_1,s_2\in R$ be such that $\text{gcd}(s_1,s_2)=1$ and $r_1s_1+r_2s_2=0$.

Then letting $s_k=0$ for $3\le k\le n-1$, it follows that $\text{gcd}(s_1,...,s_{n-1})=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_ks_k=0$.

Let $y_n=x_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_kx_k$ and let $y_1'=y_1-a_ny_n$.

Then $y_1'=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_kx_k$ where $b_k=a_k-s_ka_n$.

Suppose $f\in R$ is a common divisor of $b_1,...,b_{n-1}$.

Identically we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_kb_k
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_k(a_k-s_ka_n)
\\[4pt]
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_ka_k-a_n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_ks_k
\\[4pt]
&=
g-(a_n)(0)
\\[4pt]
&=
g
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $f{\,\mid\,}g$.

Then $f{\,\mid\,}a_k$ for all $k\in\{1,...,n-1\}$ and $\text{gcd}(f,a_n)=1$.

Then for all $k\in\{1,...,n-1\}$
\begin{align*}
&
f{\,\mid\,}b_k
\\[4pt]
\implies &
f{\,\mid\,}a_k-s_ka_n
\\[4pt]
\implies &
f{\,\mid\,}s_ka_n
\\[4pt]
\implies &
f{\,\mid\,}s_k
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, since $\text{gcd}(s_1,...,s_{n-1})=1$, it follows that $f$ is a unit of $R$.

Thus we have $\text{gcd}(b_1,...,b_{n-1})=1$.

Applying the inductive hypothesis, there exist $y_2,...,y_{n-1}\in \langle{x_1,...,x_{n-1}}\rangle$ such that $\langle{y_1',y_2,...,y_{n-1}}\rangle=\langle{x_1,...,x_{n-1}}\rangle$.

Now consider $\langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle$.

It's clear that $y_1,...,y_n\in\langle{x_1,...,x_n}\rangle$.

From $y_1'=y_1-a_ny_n$, we get $y_1'\in \langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle$.

Hence from $\langle{y_1',y_2,...,y_{n-1}}\rangle=\langle{x_1,...,x_{n-1}}\rangle$, we get $x_1,...,x_{n-1}\in \langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle$.

And then from $y_n=x_n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_kx_k$, we get $x_n\in \langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle$.

Thus $x_1,...x_n\in \langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle$, hence $\langle{y_1,...,y_n}\rangle=\langle{x_1,...,x_n}\rangle$, which completes the induction, and thus completes the proof.

Comment: It can be a good algorithm for generating unimodular matrix using row elimination though it doesn't really need $ \mathrm{gcd} (r_1,r_2,\dots,r_{n-1)=1 $